# Enforcing a business rule operating on aggregate root collections

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have 2 Aggregate Roots (ARs) in my domain:

1. Product - I guess the name says it all - it's the thing the partner sells. It belongs to:
2. Partner - the seller.

It's a multitenant system and one of its assumptions is that a Partner can have hundreds of thousands of products depending on a limit - if company A wants to sell only 100 products, they buy the cheapest, Bronze Pass and if they want to sell 100 000 products, they buy the Gold Pass. During the product import process, those rules should be enforced, so at any given moment no partner should be able to keep more products in our system than the limit rule allows.

The Product AR is a big one - it contains ~10 business rules and ~12 ValueObjects. The Partner AR is a small one - it contains only the Id and current limit value.

How the import process looks from the code perspective:
I'm loading the Partner from the database and I assign it with a collection of ids of currently active products. Then, when the product data comes in, I first run it through a method: Partner.LimitProducts(Products) that returns a list of products allowed to be put in the database.

I didn't make products as a strict part of the partner aggregate (so an entity belonging to it) for two reasons:

1. Performance - I'm using a NoSql - document database and it wouldn't handle keeping huge documents well.
2. Common sense - it's no accident that the product AR is so big, as 99.999% of the action happening in the microservices being discussed is only about a product and it never even touches the Partner - apart from creating new products, that is.

However I see some problems with this approach. To me, DDD is all about making strong guarantees in the aggregates (the invariants), however when I use one AR as a kind of a filtering layer to the other one, in this one case, it immediately forces me to put the coordination logic a layer above the two ARs involved and this just looks to me that half of the invariant is in a wrong place (which would be the application layer), but where should it be? I considered creating a domain service to place the coordination logic inside or even move the limit business rule there, but I don't know if I like that...

Do any of you see an alternative design for this?

Answer (score 0):

If the partner aggregate only has the limit, that suggests to me that you either:

- give the partner aggregate responsibility for the coordination (e.g. require that product creation (and deletion, for whatever deletion means in your domain) go through the partner aggregate)
- get rid of the partner aggregate because it's serving no purpose in your domain

I would probably have the partner aggregate keep (ideally in a set, if your language/DB can efficiently maintain such) track of which products (only the ID is needed) are associated with the partner.  If that proves to be too big to persist reliably, I would then shard the product set and effectively make each shard its own aggregate (you could get really clever and adaptively shard the aggregate).

Comment: That your description says "no partner should be able to keep more products" also strongly suggests that product creation/loading goes through the partner aggregate.

Comment: I thought about this approach and there's one reason I don't like it: the product aggregate list will only go through the partner aggregate if new products are added, so that the number of products exceeding the partner limit will not be passed through. However, in every other case (and as I said, there's 10+ product actions and there will be more) partner aggregate stays put, as the actions are performed only on products.

Comment: Effectively making partner manage their product in this situation will only lead to reduntant partner aggregate methods.

Comment: My current idea is to make the partner just an entity - kind of a configuration data bag, as that's what it mostly is - and always push new products through a domain service enforcing that limit rule. Seems procedural and something feels wrong, but I think it's the only way to make it both - storage optimal and readable.